# Comparing dates in SQL Server when using convert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query that returns all the records when a certain column (value) is older than 1/1/1996. The data type of the column is `varchar`, so I'm converting it first to a `datetime` format.

Here is the query:

```
select *
from T1
where convert(varchar(20), convert(datetime, value), 113) > convert(varchar(20),   convert(datetime, '1/1/1996'), 113)
```

I'm getting many results, including records with date < 1/1/1996

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" - you can comparing _strings_ instead of _dates_.

Comment: Fundamentally what you're doing wrong is storing dates as strings .You need to change the datatype to a date data type as soon as you can.

Comment: I'll just leave this here...[Aaron Bertrand - Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, in an ideal world that would be perfect, but that's not possible with this customer that has a very old system and needs to be maintained. Maybe you can help providing an answer to my question?

Comment: Plenty of other people have short term answers for you. Long term this is called 'technical debt' and that's a term I try to use a lot to help customers understand this kind of situation. I completely understand the situation but it wasn't clear to me whether you were building this from scratch or working on a legacy system.

Answer (score 4):

Just compare dates:

```
 where convert(datetime, value, 113) < '1996-01-01'
```

Only convert if you need to, for some reason.

And for constants, use ISO standard formats such as YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: [ISO format](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2009/12/08/unambiguous-date-formats-t-sql-tuesday-001.aspx) is not always right. `YYYYMMDD` will be safer to use

Comment: I tried this, but I get "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" My data looks like this '10/9/2001 11:00:00 PM'

Comment: @LEM that would be because '10/9/2001 11:00:00 PM' isn't format `113` which is `Europe default + mmilliseconds or don mon yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmm(24hr)`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to CONVERT or CAST datetimes in SQL Server.  Others have covered `CONVERT(datetime,value,113)` very well but I noticed your comment that `'10/9/2001 11:00:00 PM'` failes conversion and that would be because format `113` is `Europe default + mmilliseconds` or `don mon yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmm(24hr)`.

So you would have to use another format for it to work, but if you read the list of available formats here at Microsoft's documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx.

So `'10/9/2001 11:00:00 PM'` is either `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` or `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`  and neither of those formats is one the list.

Which means that you will either have to cut up and re-arrange the string or simply use another conversion method.

If `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` format simply use `CAST('10/9/2001 11:00:00 PM' AS DATETIME)`

If `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` format that is a bit more complicated but you can use `TRY_PARSE('10/9/2001 11:00:00 PM' AS DATETIME USING 'en-GB')` if you have SQL Server 2012+.

For this very reason is why DATETIMEs should never be stored as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select *
from T1
where convert(datetime, value, 113) < convert(datetime, '1/1/1996', 113)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does intrinsic data conversions, so if your column were to be DATE, then this would be real easy.

However, since it is stored as a string (which is a very very bad idea), you have to convert it to a DATE first before using it.

First, test your column to make sure you can actually convert everything

```
Select Distinct Convert (DateTime, Value, 113) ConvertedDate From T1
```

If this works without a hitch, then convert your string column to a date using `CONVERT`, and then compare:

```
Select *
From T1
Where Convert (DateTime, Value, 113) > '1/1/1996'
```

If you have some funky values in there, then use an `ISDATE` to filter out good data

```
Select *
From T1
Where ISDATE (Value) = 1
   And Convert (DateTime, Value, 113) > '1/1/1996'
```